# TypeError: Medal.__new__() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'athlete', 'team', and 'event

Tags: python, numpy, collections, list-comprehension

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[19], line 1
----> 1 medals =[Medal(line.split('\t')) for line in open('goldmedals.txt','r')]
      2 medals[:10]

Cell In[19], line 1, in <listcomp>(.0)
----> 1 medals =[Medal(line.split('\t')) for line in open('goldmedals.txt','r')]
      2 medals[:10]

TypeError: Medal.__new__() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'athlete', 'team', and 'event'
```

```
import collections

import numpy as np

open('goldmedals.txt','r').readlines()[:10]
```

```
["1992\tA Dijiang\tCHN\tBasketball Men's Basketball\tNA\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n",
 "2012\tA Lamusi\tCHN\tJudo Men's Extra-Lightweight\tNA\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n",
 "1920\tGunnar Nielsen Aaby\tDEN\tFootball Men's Football\tNA\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n",
 "1900\tEdgar Lindenau Aabye\tDEN\tTug-Of-War Men's Tug-Of-War\tGold\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n",
 "1988\tChristine Jacoba Aaftink\tNED\tSpeed Skating Women's 500 metres\tNA\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n",
 "1988\tChristine Jacoba Aaftink\tNED\tSpeed Skating Women's 1,000 metres\tNA\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n",
 "1992\tChristine Jacoba Aaftink\tNED\tSpeed Skating Women's 500 metres\tNA\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n",
 "1992\tChristine Jacoba Aaftink\tNED\tSpeed Skating Women's 1,000 metres\tNA\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n",
 "1994\tChristine Jacoba Aaftink\tNED\tSpeed Skating Women's 500 metres\tNA\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n",
 "1994\tChristine Jacoba Aaftink\tNED\tSpeed Skating Women's 1,000 metres\tNA\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n"]
```

```
Medal = collections.namedtuple('Medal', ['year','athlete','team','event'])

m = Medal('1992', 'A Dijiang', 'CHN', 'Basketball Men\\'s Basketball')

m
```

```
Medal(year='1992', athlete='A Dijiang', team='CHN', event="Basketball Men's Basketball")
```

```
m[0], m[3]
```

```
('1992', "Basketball Men's Basketball")
```

```
m.year, m.athlete, m.team
```

```
('1992', 'A Dijiang', 'CHN')
```

```
medals = [line.split(',') for line in open('goldmedals.txt','r')]

medals[:10]
```

```
[["1992\tA Dijiang\tCHN\tBasketball Men's Basketball\tNA\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n"],
 ["2012\tA Lamusi\tCHN\tJudo Men's Extra-Lightweight\tNA\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n"],
 ["1920\tGunnar Nielsen Aaby\tDEN\tFootball Men's Football\tNA\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n"],
 ["1900\tEdgar Lindenau Aabye\tDEN\tTug-Of-War Men's Tug-Of-War\tGold\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n"],
 ["1988\tChristine Jacoba Aaftink\tNED\tSpeed Skating Women's 500 metres\tNA\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n"],
 ["1988\tChristine Jacoba Aaftink\tNED\tSpeed Skating Women's 1",
  '000 metres\tNA\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n'],
 ["1992\tChristine Jacoba Aaftink\tNED\tSpeed Skating Women's 500 metres\tNA\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n"],
 ["1992\tChristine Jacoba Aaftink\tNED\tSpeed Skating Women's 1",
  '000 metres\tNA\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n'],
 ["1994\tChristine Jacoba Aaftink\tNED\tSpeed Skating Women's 500 metres\tNA\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n"],
 ["1994\tChristine Jacoba Aaftink\tNED\tSpeed Skating Women's 1",
  '000 metres\tNA\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n']]
```

```
medals =[Medal(*line.split(',')) for line in open('goldmedals.txt','r')]

medals[:10]
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[12], line 1
----> 1 medals =[Medal(*line.split(',')) for line in open('goldmedals.txt','r')]
      2 medals[:10]

Cell In[12], line 1, in <listcomp>(.0)
----> 1 medals =[Medal(*line.split(',')) for line in open('goldmedals.txt','r')]
      2 medals[:10]

TypeError: Medal.__new__() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'athlete', 'team', and 'event'
```

Comment: Nice error, what is your question about it?

Answer (score 0):

It appears the error is that you're splitting lines in `goldmedals.txt` on `,` but fields in the file are actually separated with `\t`.

When you split on the `,` that isn't there, you get a list with a single string. Your named tuple requires four arguments, so when you expand out your list with one element, it tells you you're missing four minus one or *three* arguments.

Now, your data contains a lot of tabs, so if you split on tabs, you'll want to slice the first four results and expand that into the `Medal` constructor or you'll get errors about giving too many arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the actual question you are asking so apologies if you know this already, but the error you are getting stems from the fact that you are doing a line.split(',') on valid data that contains a comma (,), e.g. "Speed Skating Women's 1,000 metres" For rows like this, it's going to split at the comma in 1,000. Then when you try to construct Medal(), it won't have enough params. Try splitting at the tab character ('\t') instead.